# PHP script with Foreach Loop running with cron - takes too long - how to do it faster

Tags: php, performance, cron

I am trying to create a website monitoring webapp with PHP. The URLs of the websites to monitor are stored in a MySQL table. A script is run every minute via cron - it loops through all the websites and foreach URL it uses CURL to visit the site and CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE to get the HTTP code - it returns true if the website is up and false if not.

The script is working OK - with one or two websites it is taking milliseconds to run but with 20 sites it is taking on average 2-15 seconds to run. I can see that this will cause problems when more sites are added - ideally I need thousands of sites to be monitored and users to be able to add their own sites.

I have thought about individual crons and files being added for each URL when a user adds a site to monitor - however I'm not sure how to go about it and I can foresee some problems as I am working on a shared server.

So how should I go about this or is there a better way that I haven't thought of?

```
<?php

function visit($url) {   
       // VISITS WEBSITE - RETURNS TRUE IF SITE UP, FALSE IF DOWN
}

// GETS THE MONITOR DETAILS FROM DATABASE
$monitor = new Table($monitorInstance);
$all_monitors = $monitor->get('monitors');
$monitors = $monitor->tableData();

//LOOP THROUGH ALL MONITORS
foreach ($monitors as $monitor1) {

       $id = $monitor1->id; //GETS ID
       $website = $monitor1->url; //GETS URL
       $status = $monitor1->status; //GETS STATUS - 'up' or 'down'

       // RUNS FUNCTION
       if (visit($website)) {
             $new_status = 'up';
       } else {
              $new_status = 'down';
       }

       // IF STATUS CHANGE UPDATE THE DATABASE
       if ($new_status != $status) {

              try {
                     //update the database with the new status
                     $monitor->update('monitors', $id, array(
                            'status' => $new_status,
                     ));

              } catch(Exception $e) { //catch exceptions
                     die($e->getMessage());
              }


              // ALSO SEND EMAIL TO USER


       }
}
```

Comment: `it uses CURL to visit the site and fetch the HTTP code - it returns true if the website is up and false if not` why not curl only the header and check the http-status-code instead of getting full content of the page?

Comment: And why not `update` the `monitors` with all new values at once instead of doing multi sql querys?

Comment: Why dont you take a look at multi curl where you can do the requests simultaneously

Comment: What @JustOnUnderMillions said

Comment: I was using curl only on the header - apologies and have edited the question to make this clearer. I will look into multi curl to make requests simultaneously - thanks @frz3993.

Comment: Will also look at updating the monitors with all values at once. @JustOnUnderMillions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Run requests in parallel

PHP generally isn't that great at parallel tasks, but it's certainly possible. In short, a HTTP request is a very slow task - there's a lot of back-and-forth between your server and the remote one. PHP is generally designed to be *sequential* - that means it does one thing at a time. So, it ends up wasting a lot of time simply **waiting for the remote servers to respond**, one at a time.

- Send off one request
- Wait for ages
- Send off one request
- Wait for ages
- etc!

What you'll want to do instead is make sure you send out lots of requests together, then wait for them simultaneously. Fortunately, PHP provides [multi curl](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-add-handle.php) to do exactly this.

Here's an example function from [this great post](https://www.phpied.com/simultaneuos-http-requests-in-php-with-curl/) on the subject:

```
<?php
 
function multiRequest($data, $options = array()) {

  // array of curl handles
  $curly = array();
  // data to be returned
  $result = array();

  // multi handle
  $mh = curl_multi_init();

  // loop through $data and create curl handles
  // then add them to the multi-handle
  foreach ($data as $id => $d) {

    $curly[$id] = curl_init();

    $url = (is_array($d) && !empty($d['url'])) ? $d['url'] : $d;
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // post?
    if (is_array($d)) {
      if (!empty($d['post'])) {
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POST,       1);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $d['post']);
      }
    }

    // extra options?
    if (!empty($options)) {
      curl_setopt_array($curly[$id], $options);
    }

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
  }

  // execute the handles
  $running = null;
  do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
  } while($running > 0);


  // get content and remove handles
  foreach($curly as $id => $c) {
    $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
  }

  // all done
  curl_multi_close($mh);

  return $result;
}

?>
```

The usage of the above is like so:

```
<?php 

// An array of all the URLs to load:
$data = array(
  'https://..',
  'https://..',
  'https://..'
);

// Load them now:
$r = multiRequest($data);

// r contains an array of responses.
print_r($r);

?>
```

There are also various libraries like [Parallel Curl](https://github.com/petewarden/ParallelCurl/blob/master/parallelcurl.php) too.

Comment: To avoid crashing your initcwnd you really should the size of your batch (to less than 20 requests). And set a timelimit on the requests.

Comment: Thanks - this is a great help.